# Word VSTO - Finding the location of a shape in the document?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, position, vsto, page-setup

I am building a Word VSTO (VB.NET) program where I need to find the exact position in Points of a shape from Top, Left, Right and Bottom. I use the following code,

```
objShape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes(intShapesLoop)

objShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin

objShape.Select()

sngPageWidth = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.PageSetup.PageWidth
sngPageHeight = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.PageSetup.PageHeight

sngMarginsLeft = objShape.Left + Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.PageSetup.LeftMargin
sngMarginsRight = sngPageWidth - (objShape.Width + sngMarginsLeft + sngGutterPosistionRight)
```

This works fine and shows the correct location values from Left and Right. However, I use the below code for the Top and Bottom locations,

```
sngMarginsTop = objShape.Top + Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.PageSetup.TopMargin
sngMarginsBottom = sngPageHeight - (objShape.Height + sngMarginsTop)
```

This shows the wrong position values. What is the issue here? From the Top value it shows about 12 Points less than the correct value

I found that this happens only on few documents. It shows the correct Top value on most documents but on few it shows the wrong Top value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason why the top value is wrong,

In the Advanced Layout dialog (***Text Wrapping > More Layout Options...***),

[image]

The combo boxes marked by the red rectangles have to be set as **Margin**. The reason the top value was wrong is because the **Absolute position ... below** is set to **Paragraph** instead of **Margin**. When this is set to **Margin** the top value became correct.